# Why bzip2 --version behaves strange?

Tags: io-redirection, bzip2

So if I enter the command

```
$ gzip --version | head -n1
```

everything goes as expected. But if I try the same with bzip2:

```
$ bzip2 --version | head -n1
```

I get a lot of lines and I have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> to terminate.

What is happening here?

EDIT:

The lines being printed by

```
$ bzip2 --version | head -n1

bzip2, a block-sorting file compressor.  Version 1.0.6, 6-Sept-2010.

Copyright (C) 1996-2010 by Julian Seward.

This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms set out in the LICENSE file, which is included
in the bzip2-1.0.6 source distribution.

This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
LICENSE file for more details.
```

and i have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> to continue.

If I omit the pipe I get

```
$ bzip2 --version 

bzip2, a block-sorting file compressor.  Version 1.0.6, 6-Sept-2010.

Copyright (C) 1996-2010 by Julian Seward.

This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms set out in the LICENSE file, which is included
in the bzip2-1.0.6 source distribution.

This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
LICENSE file for more details.

bzip2: I won't write compressed data to a terminal.
bzip2: For help, type: `bzip2 --help'.
```

If I merge stdout with stderr as @devnull sais, it displays the lines well, but i need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>. I tried

```
$ gcc 2>&1 | head -n1
```

and it works well, so I think there is something still missing in the `bzip2` command.

EDIT 2:

I solved the issue with the following command:

```
$ bzip2 --version 2>&1 < /dev/null | head -n1
```

But I still don't understand the problem.

Comment: Could you show some of the lines being printed? Does `\bzip2 --version 2>&1 | head -n1` work better?

Comment: The version # appears and the license block. If the pipe is removed, I see also: "bzip2: I won't write compressed data to a terminal."

Comment: @terdon It works better, but i still have to press Ctrl-C, and I don't know why.

Comment: Please post the output of `type bzip2` and `type head`.

Comment: @terdon `type bzip2` gives `bzip2 is /usr/bin/bzip2`. `type head` gives `head is /usr/bin/head`.

Comment: There is something going on here that is specific to your system. I can't reproduce the issue. Could you update your question with the result of `bzip2 --version` alone, the error message about compressed data sounds like it is attempting to compress something. Do you get the same behavior if you run the command in a different directory?

Comment: @terdon I tried running it in different directories and I always get the same. I'm running Arch linux and `zsh`, but the same happens in `bash`.

Comment: Very strange, the message about compressed data means it is actually trying to compress something for some reason. Both you and @illuminÉ seem to get the same thing but I can't reproduce it on Debian. I wonder if `/usr/bin/bzip2` is not a link to a script or similar.

Comment: @terdon I have bzip2 in /bin but behavior is similar and output identical to OP. I do need to interrupt too to get the prompt back. I'm on Gentoo, 64bit only.

Answer (score 7):

The difference is that `gzip --version` outputs to `STDOUT` while `bzip2 --version` outputs to `STDERR`.

Merge `STDERR` into `STDOUT` and you'd see the *expected*:

```
$ bzip2 --version 2>&1 | head -n1
bzip2, a block-sorting file compressor.  Version 1.0.6, 6-Sept-2010.
```

Comment: That's better, but still doesn't work as expected, I have to press Ctrl-C as before.

Comment: @Msegade That's odd.  I just tried it and don't need to interrupt to get the prompt.